# Unity gain circuit with LF353 is creating gain over 1 for low signals

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, unity-gain

I have larger curciut with a small stage for signal decoupling and stabilization using a unity gain amplifier based on an LF353. I don't have any real requirements for speed. My signal input is quite high in impedance though, thus, the j-fet opamp.
Input to this circuits can range from 0 to 5V.
After this stage, the signals are fed into an ADC.

You can see the relevant part of the circuit in the image.

[image]

The second opamp is used for the reference voltage. You can ignore it, it works as it should.

My problem is as follows:

For large and medium signals all works well. For example, an input signal of 2.5V is nicely converted into an output signal of 2.5V.
However, low signals do not behave properly. When I, for example, supply a signal of 250mV, the output is around 7V (9V supply in contrary to the image). (I can deliver the precise point of changed behaviour and precise voltages if that helps in any way.)
I am aware, that the LF353 is not a rail to rail-capable opamp. So I do not expect the signal to go down to 0V and that there will be non-linearities for voltages close to the rail. But I would have assumed they will be clipped, not amplified?

Is there something wrong with my understanding on how this circuit works? Any ideas of what is going on an how to fix it?

Also, sorry in advance if thats a stupid or already explained question. In that case I am probably very blind while googling and would be happy with a link :-)

Thanks for any help,

Mr.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LF353 has an input range that only extends to V- +3V so for inputs less than 3V (typica) the output may go high (since V- is 0V in your circuit). Refer to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf).

> Exceeding the negative common-mode limit on either input will force
> the output to a high state, potentially causing a reversal of phase to
> the output. Exceeding the negative common-mode limit on both inputs
> will force the amplifier output to a high state. In neither case does
> a latch occur since raising the input back within the common-mode
> range again puts the input stage and thus the amplifier in a normal
> operating mode.

The output also won't swing all the way to V-.

You should use a different op-amp, a single-supply type or an op-amp with rail-to-rail inputs and outputs. Or add a negative supply of at least -3V (since that's typical, I would suggest at least -5V).